# Unicode-math: sans-Italic-Latin ending up upright

Tags: unicode-math

The following MWE

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    %\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\begin{document}

$=\mitsansa=\msansa=$.

$=\mitsansA=\msansA=$.

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

I wonder how can I access Sans, Italic, Latin symbols.

Comment: `\usepackage[sans-style=literal]{unicode-math}` seems to fix it.

Comment: It does! But why!!?

Comment: I don't know, otherwise I would give an answer instead of a comment :-)

Comment: I think I now know. Recall that inputting upright latin `$A$` will end up in italic, because that is the convention for TeX. Unicode-math introduces a mechanism that changes the "uprightness" of a character depending on whether it is Latin/Greek, sans/serief, md/bold. It happens that sans is default to upright, hence the result.

Comment: What about `\symsfit`? `$ = \symsfit{a} = $.` and `$ = \symsfit{A} = $.` give [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgPl0.png).

Comment: @frougon That could work. Although my intention is to use `` and `` in my source code. So things like `\mathxxx{A}` are not preferred.